# Nested @Transactional

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, transactions, transactional

Is it possible to nest @Transactional annotated methods in spring? Consider something like this:

```
@Transactional
public void a() {
    obj.b();
}

@Transactional
public void b() {
    // ... 
}
```

What happens in such a case if I rollback in b() and rollback in a() ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The second *`@Transactional`* annotation on method `b()` is not required because by default *`@Transactional`* has a propagation of `REQUIRED`, therefore methods called by method `a()` will be transactional.  If you are looking to start a new transaction within a method called by method `a()` you will need to modify the propagation rules. Read about [Transaction Propagation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation).

Comment: Since `b` is public, what if other callers use it independently of `a`?  Then what is the best practice?

Comment: I think if It's public then It must have @Transactional annotation. In my case I had to change to private visibility.