# Nested @Transactional annotation behaviour on Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity `User`, a Repository/Dao class `UserDao` (using **Spring Data JPA**) and a Service class `UserService` with a method `addUser` annotated as `@Transactional`:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

  @Autowired
  private UserDao userDao;

  @Transactional
  public void addUser() throws Exception {

    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername("aaa");

    // Save the user, but since this method have the @Transactional
    // annotation it should not be committed....
    userDao.save(user);

    // Forcing an error here I expected that the previous operation
    // were rolled back.. Instead the user is saved in the db.
    if ("".equals("")) {
      throw new Exception("something fails");
    }

    // Other operations (never executed in this example)
    user.setUsername("bbb");
    userDao.save(user);

    return;
  } // method addUser

} // class UserService
```

The `UserDao` is simply this:

```
@Transactional
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> { }
```

Reading the Spring Data JPA [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-propagation) and other questions on the same argument ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156236/nested-transaction-using-spring-and-hibernate?rq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633870/nested-transactional)) my expectations were that each operations inside a method marked with `@Transactional` will be rolled back if some error occurs..

**What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way for rollback the save operation in the previous example if an error occurs?**

Comment: btw CRUD methods are by default transactional, so you don't have to mark your repos explicitely - http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#transactions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct however automatic rollback only occurs for runtime, unchecked exceptions.

So, assuming your transaction manager is configured correctly, to rollback on a non-runtime, checked exception add the rollbackFor attribute to your transactional annotation:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void addUser() throws Exception {

}
```

Comment: yes!.. thanks, I changed `Exception` to `RuntimeException` and now all works as I expected. Do you have some reference when this is well explained?

Comment: See the following which gives some examples: http://simplespringtutorial.com/springDeclarativeTransactions.html

Comment: What is the reason for that? Why only unchecked exceptions should be cause the rollback?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add things to your Xml configuration file.. you need to add trnasaction manager.

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txMgrDataSource" />

<!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type
    DataSourceTransactionManager -->
<bean id="txMgrDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
</bean>
```

Assuming your data source is:

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="####" />
    <property name="url"
              value="jdbc:sqlConnection" />
    <property name="username" ref="user" />
    <property name="password" ref="pass" />

</bean>
```

Comment: thank you, I'm using Spring Boot with default configurations (I don't have any configuration file).

Comment: Ok, I didn't use spring boot yet.. But as much as i know he just give embedded container(Tomcat etc..). Anyway good luck :)